# Vim - close autocomplete menu and go to normal mode when pressing ESC

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm using MacVim with YouCompleteMe plugin. Everything is awesome, but I have a small problem: pressing escape only closes the autocomplete popup without returning to normal mode - it stays in insert mode. For me, this behaviour is a bit weird - I always expect Esc to mean normal mode, hence my question: Can I force Vim to close the popup menu and go to normal mode on Esc? And how?

Thank you,

t.

Comment: I'm not running macvim but the behavior you want is the behavior I get when I try this.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: When I use YouCompleteMe and hit escape I go back to normal mode.

Comment: Is your .vimrc available somewhere, like .github? I might be missing something!

Comment: It is on github and bitbucket (same username) but Its more likely your configuration see https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mostly something conflicting in your setup. Take a look at github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/9.

If you have the AutoClose plugin remove it and replace it with delimitMate

https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#nasty-bugs-happen-if-i-have-the-vim-autoclose-plugin-installed